# Why use Limsup when root test

Tags: real-analysis

I know the what the root test means and understand the proof of the test

But, i wonder why we use limsup for the test

Is it false if we change the limsup to lim or liminf?

Please give an answer

I thank for you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may happen that the $\lim$ does not exist, like in the series
$$
1+\frac13+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^3}+\frac1{2^4}+\frac1{3^5}+\dots
$$
As for the $\liminf$, the test is not valid:
$$
1+\frac12+1+\frac14+1+\frac18+\dots
$$
is divergent, but $\liminf |a_n|^{1/n}=1/\sqrt2<1$.